# Threads sharing resources C++

Tags: c++, image, concurrency, locking, ipc

I currently have two threads running in my program:

1. Main thread - Grabs image from a webcam, stored in a [CVD](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/classCVD_1_1Image.html!) image. Does processing on this image.
2. Server thread - sends the full image data stored in the above CVD image to its clients using named pipes.

When I run my program it works for a very short while before crashing with the following exception:

```
0xC000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000
```

Which I assume is because my server thread is attempting to access the image at the same time as the main thread.

I haven't done any concurrent programming before (this is my first time) but I have a vague idea about how to solve it at the moment.

My plan is to have some sort of lock that prevents access to the image from the main thread when the server is preparing to send it to the client. However I realised there might be a problem where the server thread constantly keeps the resource as the client is constantly requesting a new frame. So I am thinking to only respond to the client whenever a new frame is grabbed from the webcam to avoid the blocking issue above.

To sum this up:

Main thread:

```
1. If Image is available
   then - Lock image, copy over new data from webcam, release image
   else - goto 1
2. Do processing
```

Server:

```
1. Receive request for new frame from client
2. If (haven't sent the current frame yet)
   then - Lock CVD image access, send over frame, release image.
   else - wait until new image available.
3. goto 1
```

My question is, would this be a suitable solution? and what do I need in order to implement this? i.e. how do I stop execution of certain parts of my code whilst another thread is executing a part of its own code.

Some more info:

1. I am using VS2010 C++
2. The client is in C# and there is only 1 client.
3. I am accessing the image data from the CVD image using image[x][y] which returns a byte value representing the intensity of the image.
4. There is a copyTo() function available with the CVD image. It seems to do a memory copy of the image to create a new object with the same data. Would this be useful?
5. I cannot run the program in debug mode because I am working off an existing codebase with no debug mode set.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. Yes, locking is *absolutely* necessary sharing resources accross threads. You may want to read on mutexes and semaphores. Normally, in most threading libraries I used anyway, the library will take care of stopping "execution of certain parts of [your] code" using system calls until the resource has been released, when done properly of course.

Comment: What do you want to do about flow-control? Typically, the webcam and the client will produce/consume data at different rates.  You should specify what you want to do when there are more images coming in than the client can consume and when the client asks for an image and there isn't one ready yet.

Comment: If there are more images coming in that the client can consume the client will simply get the latest frame back when it requests it. It doesnt matter if it drops frames inbetween calls. If the client asks for an image and a new image isn't ready, it blocks until one becomes available (i.e. the server detects the new image and sends it via the pipe to the client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a circular buffer so I could be reading one frame while writing a different one to clients, assuming you don't want to drop frames.

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx for info on Windows Critical Sections.

Finally, if you have the existing code, why can't you turn debug info on and rebuild?  Otherwise you're shooting in the dark trying to find the cause of this crash.

Comment: I implemented the critical sections and the circular buffer, works great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> how do I stop execution of certain parts of my code whilst another thread is executing a part of its own code

Synchronization will be done by the pipe itself — if you call `ReadFile()`¹  in your client it will pause its execution until some data came through it.

There are sample implementations of pipe [server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. It might help.

¹ I mean not overlapped call

Comment: The problem is not that the pipe logic itself. The byte array sent over is not a shared resource, it is a copy of the CVD image data that is created in the server thread before the WriteFile() is called to send the image to the client.

Comment: @Jkh2 As I understand you need a way to synchronize several threads. Am I correct? If so then you can use simple mutexes to protect shared resources. Also as mentioned in user80222's answer Critical Sections might fit your needs.